# Brown spots on alovera

Tags: houseplants

[image]
As you can see my aloe Vera plant is young and it is in balcony so  2-3 hrs only it is getting sunlight.Frequently the soil get dry,so I give water according to the soil condition.But some brown spots are coming now.I am worried about this.Can you please tell me the cause.